# Combining Date Start and Date End in Drupal 8 Views Block

Tags: views, theming, datetime

I am new to Drupal 8 Views - How do you concatenate Event Start Date Sept 1, 2019 with Event end Date ie: Sept 4, 2019? The end result is they just want the Month and Day to show up like this Sept 1-4.

Comment: For the most part you could do this easily with views Rewrite Results settings on each of the fields, hide the fields from display and then add a custom one to render the field tokens. I’m not sure about views handling instances where your end date crosses over to a new month... Sep 4 - Oct 2.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom field formatter plugin](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0) for the `daterange` field type and you can use it at other places on the website too.

Comment: Love it thanks for confirming. Makes the most sense too. Thanks my friend